# Prove that sum is finite with the help of generating function

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, derivatives, power-series, generating-functions

Please help me to prove that the following sum is finite
$$
\sum_{j=2l-2}^{\infty}j!\, a_j^{(l)}, 
$$
here the generating function of $\displaystyle{a_j^{(l)}}$ is $\displaystyle{\left(\frac{e^{x/6}\sin{\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}\right)^l}.$

I.e., we should show convergence of
$$
\sum_{j=2l-2}^{\infty}j!\, \left[\left(\frac{e^{x/6}\sin{\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}\right)^l\right]^{(j)},
$$
where one should take the $(j)$-th derivative at $x=0$, i.e. limit when $x$ approach to zero.
$$
$$
This question was posted by another user under the different contekst here [Prove that sum is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241549/prove-that-sum-is-finite) and someone gave an idea that maybe generating function would be of help.

I was trying to study a generating functions (its not my field) but I did not succeed. So I've asked this: Find generating function $\sum_{j}a_jx^j$ so that allows to find all of $a_j^{\ell}$. (see [Construct a generating function for the components of a sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295684/construct-a-generating-function-for-the-components-of-a-sum)).

Now, I am trying to use this generating function, but I am still far away from the solution. As I understand correctly, now instead of $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}j!\, a_j^{(l)}$ I have series with the $\ell$-th derivative of a generating function. But is it really simplify the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Please reread Antonio's answer in your $2^{nd}$ link. If you understand his answer, then you will immediately see the generation function for $a_j^{(l)}$ is given by $\left(\frac{e^{x/6}\sin{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^l$.

Comment: No,  I have hot whats the generating function. My question is how to show that series is convergentn...